# How to use the variable of FirebaseReference.observeSingleEvent into another function

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, closures

I want to use **variable_a** in another function. Actually, I want to load these data into tableviewcell.

```
func readFIRData()  {
    var credentials:[String]
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("usr").child(userID!)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let Name = value?["firstName"] as? String ?? ""
        let PhoneNo = value?["mobile"] as? String ?? ""


        var variable_a = [Name,PhoneNo]


        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }) { (error) in
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a callback (completion handler) in your `readFIRData` function, and pass **variable_a** as a parameter in that callback. Parse it into object which you use in table view, and reload tableView in the callback.

Function should look like this:

```
func readFIRData(_ completion: ([Name,PhoneNo]) -> ())  {
    var credentials:[String]
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("usr").child(userID!)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let Name = value?["firstName"] as? String ?? ""
        let PhoneNo = value?["mobile"] as? String ?? ""

        var variable_a = [Name,PhoneNo]
        completion(variable_a)
    }) { (error) in
    }
}
```

and then have another function which is going to call `readFIRData` function:

```
func requestData() {
   readFIRData() { [weak self] data in
        guard let `self` = self else { return }
        self.data = data
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
   }
 }
```

Mention how you get back to main thread to reload tableView. By self.data I assumed data which you will use in table view to instantiate cells.

Comment: could you please explain more on
           func readFIRData(_ completion: ([Name,PhoneNo]) -> ())  {
this line.. something seems to wrong
Errors: , or : expected
           undeclared type

Comment: Yes, this is the function which accepts one parameter: completion callback. completion callback has one parameter of type [Name, PhoneNo] and returns () which is void. Everything else I copied from your code, except for tableView reloading, and added completion call with **variable_a** as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this way

```
 func GetData(completion: @escaping(_ credentials: [String]) -> Void)  {
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("usr").child(userID!)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    let Name = value?["firstName"] as? String ?? ""
    let PhoneNo = value?["mobile"] as? String ?? ""


    var variable_a = [Name,PhoneNo]

    completion(variable_a)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}) { (error) in
}
}
```

Now, assign **StringArray** to some variable. Use below code to assign. Likewise variable **StringArrayVariable** can be used to populate tableview cells.

```
GetData { (StringArray) in
        self.StringArrayVariable= StringArray
    }
```